# How can I enforce that a user is only logged in once in Jboss/J2EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I need to enforce that some users (that have a flag at true) can only have 1 active session.
I mean, the users logs in 1 browser and can't login in another browser/computer.

I tried using my own loginmodule but the second time I login (in another browser) the loginmodule isn't used, it seems something is being cached...

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html), there is an option for [concurrent session control](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/reference/html/ns-config.html#ns-concurrent-session). You would want only 1 session. There is an explanation of [integrating Spring Security with JBoss](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/reference/html/ca.html#ca-jboss).

Comment: You can use Spring Security (previously known as Acegi Security) without using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an Application Scoped map of logged in users that you check when someone logs in. Store the session id and the user id.

Are you using a Framework? If so which one?